# Axios Promise Handling - Getting "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection - TypeError: Network request failed" in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, promise, axios

In my `react-native` application on the login screen I'm working on providing the user with nice error messaging after entering in the incorrect username / password combination. To interact with the API I'm using the library **Axios**. However when I get an error in the `catch` statement, I get this ugly error message saying that I have an "unhandled promise rejection" and I cannot do things such as set the components state or navigate to a new page.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, it looks exactly like examples I've seen in the docs.

In my form submission function I have:

```
axios.post('http://192.168.1.11:1337/login', {
  email: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password
}).then(function (response) {

  // This stuff all seems to work great
  console.log("The response we got: ", response);
  if (response.status == 200) {
    console.log("Status code equals 200");
    Actions.homepage();
  }
}).catch(function (err) {

  // Run into big problems when I get an error
  console.log("Got an error logging in, here's the message: ", err);
});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**P.S.** Here is the error message I'm getting back from the server, which get's logged from that `console.log("Got an error logging in, here's the message: ", err);`:

```
"Got an error logging in, here's the message:"

{ [Error: Request failed with status code 401]
  config: 
   { transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.11:1337/login',
    data: '{"email":"zach@homies.io","password":"dddddd"}' },
  response: 
    { data: { message: 'Invalid password', user: false },
     status: 401,
     statusText: undefined,
     headers: 
     { map: 
        { connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
          date: [ 'Thu, 31 Aug 2017 23:30:21 GMT' ],
          'x-powered-by': [ 'Sails <sailsjs.org>' ],
          vary: [ 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' ],
          'content-length': [ '52' ],
          'access-control-allow-credentials': [ '' ],
          'access-control-allow-origin': [ '' ],
          etag: [ 'W/"34-Ymi4isRxuJ6jE1EIS+AQag"' ],
          'access-control-allow-methods': [ '' ],
           'access-control-allow-headers': [ '' ],
           'access-control-expose-headers': [ '' ],
           'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ] } },
     config: 
       { transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
        transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
        headers: 
         { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
         validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://192.168.1.11:1337/login',
          data: '{"email":"zach@homies.io","password":"dddddd"}' },
       request: 
        { url: 'http://192.168.1.11:1337/login',
          credentials: 'omit',
          headers: 
           { map: 
              { accept: [ 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
                'content-type': [ 'application/json;charset=utf-8' ] } },
          method: 'POST',
          mode: null,
          referrer: null,
          _bodyInit: '{"email":"zach@homies.io","password":"dddddd"}',
          _bodyText: '{"email":"zach@homies.io","password":"dddddd"}',
          bodyUsed: true } } }
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like on the Android emulator (emulating a Samsung Galaxy S7):

[image: Yellow error bar showing "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection..."]

Comment: it could simply be that `err` or `err.response` is undefined, therefore trying to log `err.response.data` would thrown an error, therefore, though you are using `.catch` - because it throws an error, you have an unhandled rejection on your hands

Comment: I have logged err.response.data  - I even included it in the SO question. It returns the error properly from the server. @JaromandaX

Comment: in the code you clearly state `Run into big problems when I get an error` - you never say what `console.log('...', err.response.data)` outputs - you show the error message you get from the server, but that can't be `err.response.data` - that looks like it's more than just `err.response.data`

Comment: though, having read the axios documentation, I can see you seem to be doing it right (albeit making assumptions about the error)

Comment: That long error message down there is **exactly** what is output from `console.log(err)` - that is where I grabbed it from @JaromandaX. Just FYI

Comment: However, I could see how that is somewhat unclear, I'll edit  the question, so thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to read my question and at least comment! I'll be putting a bounty on the question if I don't receive an attempted answer soon.

Comment: can you expand the yellow warnings and include it in your question?

Comment: Sure, done. @GaneshCauda

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zEURbC6K
can you try this paste, see if it fix your problem

Comment: From my understanding you are connecting to ip 192.168.1.11 and port  1337. It seems when you hit the request  'http://192.168.1.11:1337/login' you are not authorised. check the service is running and port 1337 is open to handle requests. Please check the given service is working via postman or any type of authorisation required for accessing the api.

Comment: Doesn't have a sense if it throws the error when the flow enters in the catch. Check and use the last version of axios, maybe is a bug with your current version. Also, try to debug your app (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger is a good option)

Comment: What is calling this? Is it a React class? Have you tried returning the err from catch? Usually when you see a problem like this there is an upstream function that is expecting to receive something from the promise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the comments and everything, this is a side project and work got crazy busy. I'll be working on updating the question/trying some solutions based off your comments/and responding to all of y'all's questions later tonight. Thanks so much to anyone/everyone who has provided input so far. Sorry for not being responsive.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong in this snippet.

- You send a request.
- You get a 401 - unauthorized response.
- Catch receives the error and logs it.

The interesting part is why you get that unhandled promise rejection error. 
But this is thrown somewhere else. So you need to provide more of the code.

Edit:
Perhaps you just have to return your axios promise to the calling function?

Comment: Cool. I will provide more code / info tonight. Hopefully I find out the real root of the problem. Otherwise I'll accept this as the answer on the final day of the +150 rep contest. Thanks

Comment: Of course i would be glad to get the rep but i didn't fix your problem ;o)